# Transfer operator spectrum of the discretized harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, lie-algebra

I'm reading "An introduction to quantum fields on a lattice" by Jan Smit.

In chapter 2, the transfer operator ̂  is defined and shown to be equal to
$$
\hat{T} = e^{-\omega^2 \hat{q}^2/4} e ^{-\hat{p}^2/2}e^{-\omega^2 \hat{q}^2/4}
$$
(There is another question about this section: [Eigenvalue spectrum of the transfer operator for the harmonic oscillator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/502273/eigenvalue-spectrum-of-the-transfer-operator-for-the-harmonic-oscillator))

With the usual coordinate representation:
$$\hat{q} \to q , ~~~ \hat{p} \to -i \partial / \partial q$$

The coordinate representation of the ground state is given by:
$$
\langle q|0\rangle = e^{- \frac{1}{2} \sinh \tilde{\omega} \, q²}
$$
$ \tilde{\omega}$ and $\omega$ are related via
$$ \cosh \tilde{\omega} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} \omega^2$$

Now the question:
I don't know how to derive this equation:
$$
\hat{T} |0\rangle = e^{-\frac{1}{2} \tilde{\omega}}|0\rangle
$$

What I thought of so far:

- To bring $\hat{T}$ to the form  $\hat{T}=e^{-\hat{H}}$ by using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.
  But the exact BCH, $$ e^{X}e^{Y}=e^{{X+Y+[X,Y]/2}} $$ is not applicable here, since $[X,[X,Y]] \neq 0$, for $X = \hat{p}^2$ and $Y = \hat{q}^2$.
- Use the coordinate representation of $\hat{T} |0\rangle $, e.g.
  $$  e^{-\omega^2 \hat{q}^2/4} e ^{-\hat{p}^2/2}e^{-\omega^2 \hat{q}^2/4} e^{- \frac{1}{2} \sinh \tilde{\omega} \, q²}, $$
  where the last part is the ground state.
  Then I use $ e^{-\hat{p}^2/2} = 1 - \frac{p²}{2} + \frac{p^4}{8} + ...$ and then insert the coordinate representation of the momentum operator, giving a ladder of derivatives of zeroth, then second, then fourth order... But this also does not yield the desired result.

I am thankful for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting complete sets of coordinate eigenstates yields finally the result:

$$ \langle q |\hat{T} |0\rangle = 
\int dq^{\prime \prime} \int dq^{\prime} \langle q | e^{-\omega^2 \hat{q}^2/4}
|q^{\prime} \rangle \langle q^{\prime} | e^{-\hat{p}^2/2} |q^{\prime \prime} \rangle \langle q^{\prime \prime} |e^{-\omega^2 \hat{q}^2/4} |0\rangle $$

using
$$ \langle q | e^{-\omega^2 \hat{q}^2/4} |q^{\prime} \rangle=
e^{-\omega^2 q^{\prime 2}/4} \delta(q-q^{\prime}) 
$$
$$ \langle q^{\prime\prime} | e^{-\omega^2 \hat{q}^2/4} |0 \rangle=
e^{-\omega^2 q^{\prime \prime 2}/4} e^{- \frac{1}{2} \sinh \tilde{\omega} \, q^{\prime\prime 2}}
$$
and
$$ \langle q^\prime | e^{-\hat{p}^2/2} |q^{\prime \prime} \rangle= 
\sqrt{ \frac{1}{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(q^\prime-q^{\prime \prime})^2}{2}}
$$
(can be shown by inserting complete set of momentum eigenstates).
One arrives at the desired result
$$ \langle q |\hat{T} |0\rangle= e^{-\frac{1}{2} \tilde{\omega}} e^{- \frac{1}{2} \sinh \tilde{\omega} \, q^{ 2}} = e^{-\frac{1}{2} \tilde{\omega}} \langle q |\hat{T} |0\rangle $$

The only thing needed are Gauss integral and the relation $\cosh \tilde{\omega} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} \omega^2$